# Package 'libpango-1.0-0' has no installation candidate

Tags: linux, ubuntu, package-management

I'm very new linux and recently In a very bold move I installed only ubuntu 13.04 on m laptop. no I have issue and I wanna install libpango-1.0-0 package with following command :
sudo apt-get install libpango-1.0-0
I get the folowing error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libpango-1.0-0 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libpango-1.0-0' has no installation candidate
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

I think the package name is `libpango1.0-0`, not `libpango-1.0-0`.

A good way to verify package names is to search the package lists, e.g. `apt-cache search libpango`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the package isn't `libpango-1.0-0` but `libpango1.0-0`:

```
$ apt-cache policy libpango-1.0-0N: Unable to locate package libpango-1.0-0
N: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libpango-1.0-0'
$ apt-cache policy libpango1.0-0
libpango1.0-0:
  Installed: 1.32.5-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 1.32.5-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 1.32.5-0ubuntu1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

You can check all packages starting with libpango and their versions like this:

```
apt-cache policy libpango*
```